# Can the Watir::Wait.until method wait for multiple elements

Tags: cucumber, watir-webdriver

Currently, to wait for three different elements, I am calling the Watir::Wait.until method three times:

```
def wait
  Watir::Wait.until {@browser.text_field(:css => '.inputtext').exists?}
  Watir::Wait.until {@browser.text_field(:css=> '.inputpassword').exists?}
  Watir::Wait.until {@browser.button(:css => 'input#u_0_1').exists?}
end
```

Is it possible to have a single `until` method call that waits for all three elements? For example, something like:

```
def wait 
  Watir::Wait.until {@browser.text_field(:css => '.inputtext').exists?,
    @browser.button(:css => 'input#u_0_1').exists?,
    @browser.text_field(:css=> '.inputpassword').exists?}
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `until` method will wait until the last expression of the block, which is the curly braces, evaluates to true. Therefore you just need to join all the checks into a single expression. This can be done by using `&&`, `and`, `||` or `or`.

Given that you want all checks to evaluate to true, use `&&` (`and` would also work):

```
def wait 
  Watir::Wait.until {
    @browser.text_field(:css => '.inputtext').exists? &&
    @browser.button(:css => 'input#u_0_1').exists? &&
    @browser.text_field(:css=> '.inputpassword').exists?
  }
end
```